# Calls by secure port (https) do not work in istio

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I hope you can help me, I have the following problem with istio I want to receive HTTPS requests but I get the error "curl: (52) Empty response from server", however the HTTP requests work correctly, I attach my manifests.

A certificate has already been generated and a secret has been created with the .crt and .key files

I don't know what else I need so that https requests can work

**Istio Version:** 1.8.2 
**Kubectl version client:** 1.20.2

[Response for HTTP & HTTPS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lu39c.png)

[CURL -Iv for HTTPS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c04lT.png)

**Gateway.yaml**

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: eks-gateway
  namespace: development
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use istio default controller
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - mysite.domine.com
    tls:
     httpsRedirect: false
  - port:
      number: 443
      name: https
      protocol: HTTPS
    hosts:
    - mysite.domine.com
    tls:
     mode: SIMPLE
     credentialName: mysite-secret
```

**VirtualService.yaml**

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: eks-virtualservice
  namespace: development
spec:
  hosts:
  - mysite.domine.com
  gateways:
  - eks-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /WeatherForecast
    route:
    - destination:
        host: eks-service
        port:
          number: 80
  tls:
  - match:
    - port: 443
      sniHosts:
      - mysite.domine.com
    route:
    - destination:
        host: eks-service
        port:
          number: 80
```

**DestinationRule.yaml**

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: eks-destinationrule
  namespace: development
spec:
  host: eks-service
  trafficPolicy:
    loadBalancer:
      simple: LEAST_CONN
```

**Service.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: eks-service
  namespace: development
  labels:
    app: eks-app
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: container-port
      protocol: TCP
      name: http-sv
    - port: 443
      targetPort: container-port
      protocol: TCP
      name: https-sv
  selector:
    app: eks-app
```

**Deployment.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "1"
  creationTimestamp: "2021-02-12T07:40:55Z"
  generation: 1
  labels:
    app: eks-app
    app.kubernetes.io/version: v1
    draft: draft-app
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 4
  revisionHistoryLimit: 0
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: eks-app
      version: v1
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        buildID: ""
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: eks-app
        draft: draft-app
        version: v1
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: XXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/DockerRepo:v1
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        livenessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /liveness
            port: container-port
            scheme: HTTP
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 1
        name: eks-app
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: container-port
          protocol: TCP
        readinessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /readiness
            port: container-port
            scheme: HTTP
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 1
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
status:
  availableReplicas: 4
  observedGeneration: 1
  readyReplicas: 4
  replicas: 4
  updatedReplicas: 4
```

Comment: Is your gateway pod even listening on port 443?

Comment: the container port is 80, in the service I receive it at 443 and I redirect to port 80, if you mean that?

Comment: Are you talking about your gateway here? I am not asking about your application. If you get empty response, your gateway isn't responding on port 443. If it was your application issue it would be some nice HTTP response from envoy like 503 or 404

Comment: are you trying from within the cluster? try hitting the gateway pod directly on port 443.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently there is a problem between istio and eks, so I decided to install aws controller to get it to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a similar issue like with these questions: Gateway and Virtual Service definitions don't match: the gateway terminates TLS, but the virtual service is defined to receive TLS traffic.

Try just deleting the TLS part in the Virtual Service.

[How do I properly HTTPS secure an application when using Istio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65836627/how-do-i-properly-https-secure-an-application-when-using-istio)

[Kubernetes Istio exposure not working with Virtualservice and Gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66029087/kubernetes-istio-exposure-not-working-with-virtualservice-and-gateway)